# Send and receive images through kafka in json using python

Tags: python, computer-vision

I'm using Kafka pipeline for a Computer Vision project. I have to ingest JSON objects into the pipeline and receive them at the consumer end. I'm doing it like:

```
>>> a = some_image_numpy_array
>>> b = base64.b64encode(a)
>>> c = b.decode('utf-8')
```

How to decode it at consumers' end into NumPy array format again? I can't dump images into JSON as bytes. I've to convert it into a string, either using utf decoding or str().

NOTE: I can't just do base64 encoding and dump it into json, since bytes are not json serializable.

Comment: Kafka/Spark code not shown. Removed tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `base64.b64decode`

```
>>> a = some_image_numpy_array
>>> b = base64.b64encode(a)
>>> c = base64.b64decode(b)
```

Comment: It throws TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

```
%python
import base64
encoded = base64.b64encode(b'a0JD0000006SxKJMA0')
print(base64.b64decode(encoded))
```

**will give you the decode string**

```
b'a0JD0000006SxKJMA0'
```

Comment: It throws TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Why are you encoding a bytearray? In my case, it's an image. So, it'll be a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
# convert image to string
image_to_kafka = base64.b64encode(cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1]).decode()

# put string image into dictionary
some_dict = {
             'some_id': 123, 
             'image': image_to_kafka
            }

# send using your producer
producer.send('some_topic', value=some_dict)
```

In my case producer was created like:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=[kafka_server],
                     value_serializer=lambda x:json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
```

But you have to take into account that:

- You will have some lag uploading images (in my case it was 2 sec/image)
- You will have some lag in reading images (in my case it was 0.5 sec/image)

IMHO, better choice is to use some storage where you save images and send only ID and/or path to an image.